# firewalld configuration to make EC2 Amazon Linux 2 a NAT

Tags: amazon-ec2, nat, firewalld

Short question:

I'm trying to configure my own NAT instance on AWS, starting with a standard AWS Linux 2 instance, and it seems the new "right" way to configure things is with firewalld instead of iptables, so I'm looking for the equivalent to the answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/406351/how-to-configure-a-custom-nat-for-use-in-amazon-vpc/406508#406508), but with firewalld.

Longer description:

I'm 99% sure I have my VPC, subnets, and routing tables configured correctly. On the ec2 instance, I've enabled IP4 forwarding, disabled ICMP forwarding, and disabled source/destination check.

I believe the only step I'm missing is that the old, community NAT Instance AMIs run a script on startup that does this:

```
(iptables -t nat -C POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s ${VPC_CIDR_RANGE} -j MASQUERADE 2> /dev/null ||
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s ${VPC_CIDR_RANGE} -j MASQUERADE ) ||
       die
```

Based on [this how-to](https://blog.redbranch.net/2015/07/30/centos-7-as-nat-gateway-for-private-network/), I'm attempting to replicate the same functionality with firewalld, and I've done

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-source=10.0.4.0/22
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-interface=eth0
firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE -s 10.0.4.0/22
```

I've also attempted to allow `ping` for testing purposes, with

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

I can successfully ssh to the NAT Instance, I can ping the outside world from it, and I can ping it from the private subnet, but I can't ping the outside world from the private subnet. I suspect there's something wrong with my understanding of firewalld works when there's only one PHY (eth0), but ... I'm stuck. So,

a) is my base assumption that I should be using firewalld instead of iptables correct?
b) if so, how do I get NAT working with it on a single interface?

Thanks!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/939478/126632

Comment: a) cool. But b) those instructions say "You also need to assign the internal interface to a different zone other than `public`. But there's only one interface. Do I assign it to "internal"?

Comment: Having a zone defined from a source ought to be OK, but you really should have two interfaces, one on a separate private network. Otherwise nothing prevents all your other instances from accessing the Internet directly.

Comment: FYI, I've confirmed this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On EC2 you need, besides proper iptable/nftable setup, to make sure that source destination checks are disabled on EC2 level.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck